# how to generate beamer frames in a foreach loop

Tags: beamer, foreach

I need to generate several frames which each contain an image.
I was thinking of looping with \ foreach but it doesn't work

```
\foreach \nn in{1,2,...,5}{
\begin{frame}[fragile]{}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{cata-\nn.jpg}
\end{frame}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \nn in{a,b,c,duck}{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Image \nn}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-\nn}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does not work with the `fragile` option...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, that is correct. But one does not need `fragile` to "generate several frames which each contain an image".