# multido and fragile frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, multido, fragile

I'm trying to use `multido` package to create a sequence of slides with multiple code snippets using listing. Unfortunately the `fragile` option leads to the following error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

Is there any workaround? Here is a minimal code to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{test}
\begin{lstlisting}
import numpy as np
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\multido{\i=1+1}{7}{%
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{\i}
\begin{lstlisting}
import numpy as np
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

---

### Clarification from Manuel:

From my understanding, the question of the OP is the following.

- The OP wants to include `listings` (`\usepackage{listings}`) in `beamer` frames.
- In order to use `listings`, `beamer` requires the `fragile` frame option
- In addition, the OP wants to programmatically create the code for the frames, e. g. using `\usepackage{multido}` or `pgffor` package.
- The problem is that `multido` does not work together with the `fragile` option.
- **Question:** How can the OP programmatically create code for frames that contain `listings`.

Comment: Fragile is a beamer option, not an option of multido. You may have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11328/beamers-fragile-frame-as-default

Comment: @C.Peters this example you pointed only shows how to define a frame with option fragile as default.

Comment: I added an -- in my opinion -- clearer problem statement, feel free to delete it if you don't like it. I try to help :).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question but if you remove the `fragile` option that the code works.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{7}{%
\begin{frame}%[fragile]
\frametitle{\i}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you can also use the `pgffor` package to create frames in a loop, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544528/). This approach also does *not* work with the `fragile` option according to the comments.

```
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544528
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \nn in{a,b,c,duck}{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Image \nn}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-\nn}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @dr-manuel-kuehner I've updated the example, maybe it is more clear now.

Comment: @dr-manuel-kuehner ```pgffor``` gives the same error when using ```fragile``` option.

Comment: @LEo Yes, that is what I wrote in the answer: "This approach also does not work with the fragile option according to the comments." It was unclear from your question (for me) that you need the `fragile` option.